# How to generate li and anchor tag from list object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, c3.js

Below is my output which i am getting from my web service but i want to create li tag from this:

```
{"d":[{"name":"ttt","url":"bbbb"},{"name":"uuu","url":"ppp"}]}
```

How to generate li tag from this above output??

I want li tag like this:

```
<li><a href="bbb" class="mylink">ttt</li>
<li><a href="uuu" class="mylink">ppp</li>
```

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev:see updated question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should try this.

```js
var obj = {
  "d": [{
    "name": "ttt",
    "url": "bbbb"
  }, {
    "name": "uuu",
    "url": "ppp"
  }]
};

$(obj.d).each(function(i,item) {
  $("<li/>").html($("<a>").attr("href",item.url).text(item.name)).appendTo('body');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Just use jQuery `.each()` to iterate through your object, and build your `li` using jQuery:

```js
var obj = {
  "d": [{
    "name": "ttt",
    "url": "bbbb"
  }, {
    "name": "uuu",
    "url": "ppp"
  }]
};

$(obj.d).each(function() {
  var $a = $("<a/>").addClass('mylink').text(this.name).attr('href', this.url);
  $("<li/>").append($a).appendTo('body');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: where is your link? you have update snippet after giving wrong answer.

Comment: @ParthTrivedi I have updated the answer. Now, it's correct.

Comment: o men you have update your answer after down vote this is not fair yar.

Comment: @AnkitKathiriya I have updated my answer 6 minutes ago. It means that I had the correct answer when there were no other answers. I agree that it is ok to downvote me while the answer is incorrect, but I was surprised that someone downvoted my answer after the final correction for being "correct-but-edited-after-being-incorrect".

Comment: @AnkitKathiriya Nah, I'm not telling that it were you :) I just share my thoughts.

Answer (score 3):

Please have a look at this approach:

```js
var data = {"d":[{"name":"ttt","url":"bbbb"},{"name":"uuu","url":"ppp"}]};
$(document).ready(function(){
  var arrData = data.d;
  
  $.each(arrData, function( index, value ) {
   $("ul").append("<li><a href='"+value.url+"' class='mylink'>"+value.name+"</a></li>");
  });
  
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <ul>
  </ul>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

A solution in plain Javascript - step by step.

```js
var object = { "d": [{ "name": "ttt", "url": "bbbb" }, { "name": "uuu", "url": "ppp" }] };

function generate(array) {
    var ul = document.createElement('ul');
    array.forEach(function (a) {
        var li = document.createElement('li'),
            anchor = document.createElement('a');
        anchor.href = a.url;
        anchor.text = a.name;
        li.appendChild(anchor);
        ul.appendChild(li);
    });
    return ul;
}

document.body.appendChild(generate(object.d));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it without using jQuery.Also there is no `data[i]['anchor']`.I guess here you are looking for the `url` key.

HTML

```
<div id="wrapper"></div>
```

JS

```
(function(){
var x = {  
   "d":[  
      {  
         "name":"ttt",
         "url":"bbbb"
      },
      {  
         "name":"uuu",
         "url":"ppp"
      }
   ]
}
var o = x['d'];
var liElem="";
for(var a =0;a<o.length;a++){
liElem += '<li class="demoClass"><a href ="'+o[a].url+'">'+o[a].name+'</a></li>'
}
document.getElementById('wrapper').innerHTML=liElem
}())
```

[WORKING MODEL](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/6syubLty/4/)

Hope this will be useful